# What is the problem of the following code in c

Tags: c, memory

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[1] = {1};
    int b = 6;
    printf("%d\n", a[-1]);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    //printf("%d\n", (a-1 == &b));
    return 0;
}
```

I wrote the above code and found out it didn't work properly when using gcc or mingw to compile it, but when I uncommented 8th line, everything is just fine. Could anyone explain the code for me?

Comment: When you don't have the 8th line, the compiler doesn't need the variable `b`, so it eliminates it.  When you have the 8th line, then it needs `b`.  Using the negative index is undefined behaviour — anything can happen when you use it.

Comment: b's address isn't even guaranteed to be right before a. [Why does gcc reorder the local variable in function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36298567/995714), [Order of local variable allocation on the stack](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1102049/995714), [Is the order of memory addresses of successively declared variables always descending?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12438216/995714), [What is the order of local variables on the stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51867757/995714), [Are C stack variables stored in reverse?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28559007/995714)

Comment: [Can a C compiler rearrange stack variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/238441/995714)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `a[-1]` is undefined memory space.

Comment: In my opinion, stack grows to low address, I declare b after a, so b suppose to underneath a in memory, so I can access b using a[-1], and if I uncommented line 8, everything works just as I expected

Comment: @SolskGaer — there are no guarantees about the layout of the variables.  One compiler might do as you expect; others can do things differently.  You're attempting to exploit undefined behaviour; any result is valid.

Comment: @SolskGaer You can't reason about stack frame layout without a certain system in mind. In addition, if your code does questionable things beyond the scope of the C standard, the compiler might generate wrong code, regardless of memory layout.

Answer (score 0):

Invalid Index for an array, I think you meant print a[1] printf("%d\n", a[-1])

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I want to access b using a[-1]

Comment: @SolskGaer `b` and `a` might not be neighbors in memory, hence accessing `b` is wrong.

Comment: `#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int a[1] = {1};
    int *b;
    b = a-1;
    printf("Adress of a, aka a[0]: %d\n", a);
    printf("Address of a-1: %d\n", a-1);
    printf("Address of b: %d\n",b);
    printf("Value b is pointing to: %d\n", *b);
    printf("Does the address of a== adress of b? %d\n", (a-1 == b));
    return 0;
}`

Comment: @AgrudgeAmicus  The code worked as I expected when I uncommented line 8, can you explain that for me? Thanks

Comment: Sure what were you expecting

Comment: @DanielAaron printf("%d\n", a[-1]) prints 6

Comment: Little confused.
 `printf("%d\n", a[-1]);` Prints 55 for me, depends what is in address of a[-1]
`printf("%d\n", b);` Prints 6 for me since it is assigned 6
`printf("%d\n", (a-1 == &b));` Prints 0 for me since 6 != address of a - 1

If you are using codeblocks be careful, it seems to not reset the memory at that location between builds which is quite annoying.

Comment: @SolskGaer Check what https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler has commented

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677415/does-stack-grow-upward-or-downward a very detailed explanation

Answer (score 0):

`a[-1]` and `a-1` result in undefined behavior.  First, lets get a definition for array subscripting from the C11 standard section 6.5.2.1p2:

> A  postfix  expression  followed  by  an  expression  in  square  brackets
>   **[]**
>   is  a  subscripted
>   designation of an element of an array object.  The definition of the subscript operator
>   **[]**
>   is that
>   **E1[E2]**
>   is identical to
>   **(*((E1)+(E2)))**
>   .

So array subscripting follows the rules of pointer arithmetic when adding an integer to a pointer.

In defining pointer arithmetic in section 6.5.6p8, it sets some rules and behavior in place *(emphasis mine)*:

> If  both  the  pointer
>   operand  and  the  result  point  to  elements  of  the  same  array  object,  or  one  past  the  last
>   element of the array object, the evaluation shall not produce an overflow; *otherwise, the
>   behavior is undefined.*  If the result points one past the last element of the array object, it
>   shall not be used as the operand of a unary
>   *
>   operator that is evaluated.

The result of the pointer arithmetic involved in the array subscripting in your question is outside of the array object, therefore it results in undefined behavior.